# Argument of type '(prevState: Stock[]) => (Stock | Stock[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Stock[] | []>'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, mean-stack

I am learning TypeScript and I am getting the below error. I am not able to understand hint provided by error. I have written this code without TypeScript and it works like charm. How to solve this?

Error details:

```react
Argument of type '(prevState: Stock[]) => (Stock | Stock[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Stock[]>'.
  Type '(prevState: Stock[]) => (Stock | Stock[])[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Stock[]) => Stock[]'.
    Type '(Stock | Stock[])[]' is not assignable to type 'Stock[]'.
      Type 'Stock | Stock[]' is not assignable to type 'Stock'.
        Type 'Stock[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Stock': ticker, name, price, change, and 2 more.ts(2345)
```

Code:

```react
export interface Stock {
  ticker: string;
  name: string;
  price: string;
  change: string;
  percentChange: string;
  id: string;
}

export const PlayGroundWebsockets: React.FunctionComponent<unknown> = (
  props: unknown
) => {
  let stockFromServer: Stock[] = [];
  const [stockCollection, setStockCollection] = useState<Stock[]>([]);

  const displayStocks = () => {
    setStockCollection((prevState: Stock[]) => { // <- Error from here
      let result = [...prevState, stockFromServer];
      return result;
    });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The method setStockCollection should be decalred as below. Then it will show no erros in TypeScript.

```react
         setStockCollection((prevState:Stock[]) => {
            let result:Stock[] = [ ...prevState, ...stockFromServer];
            return result;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to spread the `stockFromServer` array:

```react
export const PlayGroundWebsockets: React.FunctionComponent<unknown> = (
  props: unknown
) => {
  let stockFromServer: Stock[] = [];
  const [stockCollection, setStockCollection] = useState<Stock[]>([]);

  const displayStocks = () => {
    setStockCollection((prevState: Stock[]) => {
      // let result = [...prevState, stockFromServer]; <- Before
      let result = [...prevState, ...stockFromServer];
      return result;
    });
  };
};
```